# Vb.Net Wait for webbrowser finish navigate

Tags: vb.net, browser

How can i wait till webbrowser loaded the page?

i tried:

```
webbrowser1.navigate(url)
msgbox("done")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Do While wb.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
    Application.DoEvents()
Loop
```

Comment: -1 For No explanation, using [DoEvents](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/is-doevents-evil.html) and using Sleep API unnecessarily

Comment: the first one works great, check this out, the second is really Unnecessary

Comment: You should not use DoEvents even if it 'works'- GeorgeK's answer is the correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 8):

This is the approach I used when I was having the same problem. By adding a handler you dont have to use a timer to unnecessary processing instead the event will fire as soon as the document has loaded. Dont be fooled by the name documentcompleted, it's actually waiting for the webpage to load.

```
AddHandler (webbrowser1.DocumentCompleted), AddressOf WebpageLoaded
webbrowser1.Navigate(url)

Public Sub WebpageLoaded(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("Done")
End Sub
```

Im not saying this is the best way to go but it worked well for me :)

Comment: Thank you for doing it the correct way. The accepted answer is used way too often by today's new programmers.

Answer (score 0):

I inherit a new class from WebBrowser control:

```
   Public Class WebBrowserSyncFW
        Inherits WebBrowser

        Public Async Function NavigateSync(ByVal urlString As String, Optional ByVal timeoutmillisec As Integer = 30000) As Task(Of Boolean)
            Dim IsLoaded As Boolean = False

            Me.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
            Me.Navigate(urlString)

            AddHandler Me.DocumentCompleted, Sub(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
                                                 IsLoaded = True
                                             End Sub

            For i = 1 To timeoutmillisec / 100
                Await Task.Delay(100).ConfigureAwait(False)

                If IsLoaded = True Then Return True
            Next

            Return False
        End Function

    End Class
```

Usage:

```
        If Await WebBrowserSyncFW1.NavigateSync("http://www.youtube.com") Then
            MsgBox("Page is loaded!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Else
            MsgBox("Timeout!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        End If
```